# Remove delay for some emails using SideKiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actionmailer, sidekiq

I'm using SideKiq and Redis to deliver emails asynchronously on my Rails (4.2) site but some emails take too long to send. Most emails take between 5 and 15 minutes to to be delivered (I'm not sure if this is normal and may be part of the problem). For most emails I send this wait is fine, but for confirmation emails, I need them to be sent more or less immediately.

Normally when I send an email, I send it like this:

```
UserMailer.delay.my_email(args)
```

To send an email immediately, I have tried all of the following:

```
UserMailer.my_email(args).deliver
UserMailer.my_email(args).deliver!
UserMailer.my_email(args).deliver_now
UserMailer.my_email(args).deliver_now!
```

However all of these result in a 504 error. When I try to send an email, the page waits for several seconds and then I get in my `unicorn.log` is:

```
Started POST "/my-path/" for 0.0.0.0 at 0000-00-00 00:00:00 +0000
Processing by MyController#my_path as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", ...}
  Rendered user_mailer/my_email.html.haml within layouts/user_mailer (0.0ms)
E, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00000] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:00000 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00000] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 00000 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00000]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00001]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=00001
I, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00001]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [0000-00-00T00:00:00.000000 #00001]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

This is my sidekiq.yml (the both production and preview are taking a very long time):

```
---
:concurrency: 5
:logfile: log/sidekiq.log
preview:
  :pidfile: /home/unicorn/sidekiq_preview.pid
production:
  :pidfile: /home/unicorn/sidekiq_production.pid
  :concurrency: 15
```

I'm not getting anything in my `sidekiq.log` or `mail.log`.

Comment: What is your :concurrency value in config/sidekiq.yml ??

Comment: I just tried switching from Sidekiq to Resque with the same result, there is a period of several minutes between when the email is rendered to when it is sent. Something must be up with either Redis or my mail server, I'll dig in further to see if I can find out more.

Comment: It's probably not a sidekiq issue if you can not even send an email with deliver! Maybe there is a problem with the mail server settings ? Are you these are correct ?